# Injecting interfaces into a php class

Tags: php, oop, interface

So I have the following interface defined for a car:

```
interface FuelTank
{
    public function useFuel();
}

interface WaterTank
{
    public function useWater();
}

interface CarInterface extends FuelTank, WaterTank
{
    public function drive($miles);

    public function setFuelTank(FuelTank $tank);

    public function setWaterTank(WaterTank $tank);
}
```

I have tried to build a class that implements and complies to the `CarInterface` but I'm having trouble with the injection of the FuelTank and Watertank dependancies. This is the class I came up with:

```
class Car implements CarInterface
{
    protected $fuelTank;
    protected $waterTank;

    public function drive($miles)
    {
        return $miles;
    }

    public function useWater()
    {

    }

    public function useFuel()
    {

    }

    public function setFuelTank(FuelTank $tank)
    {
        $this->fuelTank = $tank;
    }

    public function setWaterTank(WaterTank $tank)
    {
        $this->waterTank = $tank;
    }
}
```

Now when I run the following:

```
$car = new Car;
$car->setFuelTank(new FuelTank);
```

I get this message:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface FuelTank

I also can't declare the class FuelTank as I get this error instead:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class FuelTank

Can someone help me understand how to correctly implement the interface above and what's going on here?

Comment: You can not instantiate an Interface like a Class.
This is $car->setFuelTank(new FuelTank); wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename the interface FuelTank to FuelTankInterface and declare a class FuelTank which implements the FuelTankInterface. An interface cannot be instantiated.

Comment: What if the interface has been defined to me and cannot be changed? Is there anyway this interface can be implemented?

Comment: Create a class FuelTankClass which implements FuelTank. The naming is not very nice though. Why name an interface FuelTank and another interface CarInterface. Better be consistent...

Comment: Well yes, but given the interface defines the `setFuelTank` parameter as being a `FuelTank` object I can't change the class name.

Comment: No, the `setFuelTank` function accepts all objects which implement the `FuelTank` INTERFACE. Type hinting works with classes but also with interfaces! So you can call `setFuelTank` with `FuelTankClass` as parameter. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php and then somewhere in the comments.

Comment: Right you are. It seems `$fuelTank = new FuelTankClass; return $fuelTank instanceof FuelTank;` returns true. I agree the naming is not pretty but I've been given the interface and told to write a class that implements it. I'm not allowed to modify the interface.